# I am unable to write the part of the code that counts by a multiple of 6

Tags: for-loop

Write a program using the for-loop. The program should:

Take a positive integer as input.
Return a list of all the integers between 0 to the input (including the input number) which are the multiple of 6.

I am unable to write the part of the code that counts by a multiple of 6

Comment: Please, provide your code (attempt) and put a question (what exactly is the problem? Syntax error in `for` loop? Incorrect answer for some test case? You can't find out if number is multiple of `6` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate from 0 to the number. Check if the number can be divided by 6. If it is divisible add to the list.

```
  num = int(input("Enter a number"))
  list = []
  for i in range(0,num+1):
      if(i%6==0):
          list.append(i)
    
  print(list)
```